# convert Map<String, CompletableFuture<Response>> to CompletableFuture<Map<String, Response>>

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future

I have: `Map<String, CompletableFuture<Response>>`
I expect: `CompletableFuture<Map<String, Response>>`

I want the result to complete once every "inside" future has completed, and then have a Map which will map the Strings to the results of the completed.
I'm looking for an elegant way to achieve this, and tried with streams but failed for now.

I have seen a method which does a similar job but with lists here: https://github.com/spotify/completable-futures/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spotify/futures/CompletableFutures.java#L49

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around calling `join` on every `CompletableFuture`, but you can use `CompletableFuture.allOf` to schedule that action to be done when all futures are completed, so no `join` call will block a thread. Then, use the Stream API to perform the bulk operation:

```
Map<String, CompletableFuture<Response>> map = …

CompletableFuture<Map<String, Response>> f =
    CompletableFuture.allOf(map.values().toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
        .thenApply(_void -> map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().join())));
```

Answer (score 1):

The same `CompletableFutures` class which is linked to in the question, now has an [`allAsMap()`](https://github.com/spotify/completable-futures/blob/v0.3.4/src/main/java/com/spotify/futures/CompletableFutures.java#L121-L139) method, thanks to this PR: https://github.com/spotify/completable-futures/pull/70